# What should I put in so the div gets vertical align?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to put in `table-cell`, `table`, `inline-block`, `inline`, but nothing works. Do any of you know what and where should I put in to make the div that has the text inside it to be `vertical-align = middle`?

```css
.div1b {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
.div2 {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div6 {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left;
}
.div8b {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.text5 {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="BIO" class="div1b">
                <div class="div2">
                  <div class="div6">
                    <div class="div8b">
                      <p class="text5">Unge Ferrari (egentlig Stig Joar Haugen) er en norsk rapper, sanger og låtskriver fra Hamar. Han debuterte i 2015 med albumet Til mine venner. Albumet inneholdt gjennombruddssinglene «Lianer» og «Hvis du vil» med Tomine Harket, og ble nominert til Spellemannprisen i kategorien «Urban». <br><br>
                        Året etter utga han EPen «Hva er vi nå // H.E.V.N. //» sammen med Tomine Harket, før han i 2017 var tilbake på egne ben med EPen «Romeo må dø». <br><br>
                        Unge Ferrari har de siste årene vært et populært navn å samarbeide med, og han har jobbet sammen med flere norske og svenske artister, som Lars Vaular, Store P, Cherrie og Silvana Imam. Hans fremste samarbeidspartner er imidlertid rapperen Arif, som han har spilt en rekke låter og konserter med. Unge Ferrari og Arif utgjør dessuten, sammen med Karpe Diem, supergruppen MARS. <br><br>
                        Unge Ferrari har en flytende sangstil som grenser mellom rap og R&B, og han bruker ofte autotune. Det er som regel Filip Kollsete og Aksel «Axxe» Carlson» som står bak produksjonene.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using display:table with vertical-align = middle.

```css
.div1b {
  width: 96%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: table;
}
.div8b {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="BIO" class="div1b">
        <div class="div8b">
          <p class="text5">Unge Ferrari (egentlig Stig Joar Haugen) er en norsk rapper, sanger og låtskriver fra Hamar. Han debuterte i 2015 med albumet Til mine venner. Albumet inneholdt gjennombruddssinglene «Lianer» og «Hvis du vil» med Tomine Harket, og ble nominert til Spellemannprisen i kategorien «Urban». <br><br>
            Året etter utga han EPen «Hva er vi nå // H.E.V.N. //» sammen med Tomine Harket, før han i 2017 var tilbake på egne ben med EPen «Romeo må dø». <br><br>
            Unge Ferrari har de siste årene vært et populært navn å samarbeide med, og han har jobbet sammen med flere norske og svenske artister, som Lars Vaular, Store P, Cherrie og Silvana Imam. Hans fremste samarbeidspartner er imidlertid rapperen Arif, som han har spilt en rekke låter og konserter med. Unge Ferrari og Arif utgjør dessuten, sammen med Karpe Diem, supergruppen MARS. <br><br>
            Unge Ferrari har en flytende sangstil som grenser mellom rap og R&B, og han bruker ofte autotune. Det er som regel Filip Kollsete og Aksel «Axxe» Carlson» som står bak produksjonene.</p>
        </div>              
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using display:flex with vertical-align = middle.

```css
.div1b {
    width: 96%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0 2%;
    display: flex;
}
.div8b { 
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="BIO" class="div1b">
        <div class="div8b">
          <p class="text5">Unge Ferrari (egentlig Stig Joar Haugen) er en norsk rapper, sanger og låtskriver fra Hamar. Han debuterte i 2015 med albumet Til mine venner. Albumet inneholdt gjennombruddssinglene «Lianer» og «Hvis du vil» med Tomine Harket, og ble nominert til Spellemannprisen i kategorien «Urban». <br><br>
            Året etter utga han EPen «Hva er vi nå // H.E.V.N. //» sammen med Tomine Harket, før han i 2017 var tilbake på egne ben med EPen «Romeo må dø». <br><br>
            Unge Ferrari har de siste årene vært et populært navn å samarbeide med, og han har jobbet sammen med flere norske og svenske artister, som Lars Vaular, Store P, Cherrie og Silvana Imam. Hans fremste samarbeidspartner er imidlertid rapperen Arif, som han har spilt en rekke låter og konserter med. Unge Ferrari og Arif utgjør dessuten, sammen med Karpe Diem, supergruppen MARS. <br><br>
            Unge Ferrari har en flytende sangstil som grenser mellom rap og R&B, og han bruker ofte autotune. Det er som regel Filip Kollsete og Aksel «Axxe» Carlson» som står bak produksjonene.</p>
        </div>              
  </div>
```